# Is there a way to have a tabbed page in a content page

Tags: xamarin.forms

There's a page in the app i'm developing currently. After some UI (image, text), i have some tabs which navigate to different pages. However, you can't have a tabbed page in a content page using the regular xamarin.forms

Comment: a TabbedPage should only be used as the root page of an app.  However, you can simulate tabbed behavior with a custom control

Comment: @Jason yea i'm aware. I need tabs in the page. More like a content page having tabs in it

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:**

Like Jason said, **custom control** could simulate tabbed behavior.

You could download from the GitHub for reference. 
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/SegmentedControlSample

For more details, you could refer to the article below.
http://www.xamboy.com/2018/01/12/segmented-bar-control-in-xamarin-forms/

[image]

**Solution2:**

You could do that with CarouselView as well.

Download from the GitHub.
https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview

For more details, you could refer to the link.
https://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/

The original image is not obvious enough, you could change `pin.png` to `icon.png` in PagerIndicatorTabs.cs.

[image]